# Query all images from phone works on api 18 but not on api 30

Tags: java, android, mediastore

**Solved by requesting permissions again at runtime**

Recently I was working on my app and I wanted to query all images on my phone so I read [Android developers tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)

And could retrieve all images normally on a phone with api 18, but when I tried it on a phone with api 30 it didn't retrieve even one image though it's the same application.

I even later tried their code to get videos but it also didn't work, so I'm now don't know what's missing, any advice would be really appreciated :(

My query code :

```
public ArrayList<CustomPhoto> getPhotosFromExternalStorage() {
        Uri collection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        } else {
            collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC";
        ArrayList<CustomPhoto> queryResult = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Cursor cursor = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                collection,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        )) {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int bucketColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            Log.e("retrieved = " , Integer.valueOf(cursor.getCount()).toString());

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Get values of columns for a given video.
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                String bucket_display_name = cursor.getString(bucketColumn);
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                Log.e("uri" , bucket_display_name);
                queryResult.add(new CustomPhoto(contentUri.toString(),bucket_display_name, name));

            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return queryResult;
    }
```

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pretest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
    <!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"-->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FacebookTest">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pretest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FacebookTest.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime, in addition to your manifest entry?

Comment: yes, as one of my tries to solve the problem I tried to check if I have the permission with an if condition, but nothing popped up to request permissions again incase I don't have them. 

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        }

Comment: yea, you're correct, it was the permissions problem, first time I tried it nothing popped up to request permissions so I thought everything was fine, but now I tried it literally just before making a query and it popped up a message requesting to allow the app read storage which was very weird :\

Comment: shouldn't having the uses-permission in the manifest  guarantee that the app having the required permissions !!?

Comment: "shouldn't having the uses-permission in the manifest guarantee that the app having the required permissions !!?" -- not since Android 6.0, six years ago.

Comment: @OmarShawky does request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission work ? Because I am currently facing this same issue.

Comment: I have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Manifest and requested it at runtime but it still crashes. My app works on API < 30

Comment: @EbenmeluNoah, will, first time I tried it as I said, it didn't show any pop-up message so I thought everything was fine, but now it shows it normally, so I don't know what changed exactly between that time and now, maybe that I was using the deprecated method in fragment to request permissions but now I switched to how I think they handle it according to android developers, anyway I can share in my post as an edit the code I'm using now to check for permissions in a fragment without using the deprecated method (which might be the case of your problem) if that might help you :thonk:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was by asking for permissions again at runtime so that is my code that worked for me after reading the following tutorial [Request app permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission):

1. First initialize an `ActivityResultLauncher` and register it as an activity result which must be before {initialization, `onAttach()`, or `onCreate()`} fragment creation methods, so the only way was to initialize it as a global fragment variable
2. Then when I need to start querying images from external storage, I use the `ActivityResultLauncher` I initialized before to launch a request for permissions needed.
3. If permissions was granted the callback should run the method responsible for getting photos, else (temporarily) it will show a toast message telling user why he can't continue with his action

My fragment code :

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) goFetchPhotos();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't continue without the required permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
//this function runs when something happens in my app
public void getNecessaryPermissionsAndFetchPhotos() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }else goFetchPhotos();
    }
```